# Is there an Admin Console for JAMES 3?

Tags: jakarta-mail, mail-server, james

I am using Java Apache Mail Enterprise Server 3. Each time I need a new user, I have to run a batch file and enter the command adduser username password. Is there any admin console for James3 like the one found for James 2.3.2 ?

Answer (score 1):

We have a Google Summer of Code Student working on Apache James Bond - a web administration tool  for James. It's work in progress but it might be useful - haven't tried it out yet.

In order to test it, you have to deploy the war in the server where you have running james, so as it has access to the configuration files, and it can connect to the jmx service in port 9999

Build the war and to run the war just type:

```
 java -Djames.conf=/opt/apache-james-3.0-beta4/conf \ 
 -Dip.range=192.168.1.* -jar bond-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

Note that you have to indicate where your conf files are, and the authorized ip address/addresses from where you are going to run the browser.

Make a COPY of your configuration files !, because bond removes all comments when saving them.

http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/bond/

Good luck,

Comment: If you test it, make sure to send your feed-back on the James Mailing list.